# Issue while creating the Project in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am writing the below command in Command prompt and things works

```
c:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

When I type below command..I am not able to create the project..Because I want this created in a directly with some suitable Name

```
c:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project laravel/Sampleproject
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should execute the below command,

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel Sampleproject
```

> `laravel/laravel` describes the package name

Answer (score 1):

The first argument you pass to the `composer`'s  `create-project` command is the project you want to use. The second parameter that you pass is the path (relative or absolute) to the directory you want the project in.

So, you got to be running this :

`composer create-project laravel/laravel C:\xampp\whatever\whatever`